# Why is ListPrice null in the QuoteLineItem before insert trigger? Is there a penalty for my work-around?

Tags: apex, trigger, issue

The `ListPrice` of a `QuoteLineItem` is null in the before insert trigger:

- what is the reason for this?
- is it an issue that could make it into a next release?

As a *work-around* I have defined a custom formula field that holds the value of `PricebookEntry.UnitPrice`. The formula field holds the correct value even in the before insert trigger. Question:

- is there any penalty (in terms of org limits or performance) in using a custom field like this (I have seen that there is a limit for custom fields which - at present - doesn't worry me)

Answer (score 1):

> what is the reason for this?

This value is not set until later. It's an automated system process that occurs when saving records to the database.

> is it an issue that could make it into a next release?

No, this is WAD (Working As Designed).

> is there any penalty (in terms of org limits or performance) in using a custom field like this (I have seen that there is a limit for custom fields which - at present - doesn't worry me)

Nothing in particular springs to mind. If this works, great.

The more standard process, though, is to explicitly query this data from the database. In the general sense:

```
Map<Id, PricebookEntry> entries = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>();
for(QuoteLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
  entries.put(record.PricebookEntryId, null);
}
entries.putAll([SELECT UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id = :entries.keySet()]);
for(QuoteLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
  PricebookEntry entry = entries.get(record.PricebookEntryId);
  // You can now do something with entry.UnitPrice
}
```

I refer to this as the [Aggregate-Query-Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern, and you'll use it pretty much everywhere, so you may as well get familiar with the practice.

While formulas do technically work, you should get in the habit of using a query, as there may be situations where you can't depend on a formula (no specific example comes to mind, but you should be aware that this technique may fail in some exotic circumstances).

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer: I felt it was odd that the `OpportunityLineItem.ListPrice` **is** available in the before insert trigger but the `QuoteLineItem.ListPrice` is not. _Also_: I was trying to avoid an extra query that would count against the per-transaction SOQL governor limit.